# quadratic equation - nature of roots

Tags: quadratics

For what values of a does the equation $$x^2-( 2^a-1)x-3(4^{a-1}2^{a-2})=0$$ possess real roots? 
Since the roots are to be real that means the discriminant should be $\geq 0$ 
$$\Rightarrow (2^a-1)^2+4\cdot 3\cdot (4^{a-1}2^{a-2}) \geq 0$$

Comment: Also, if the discriminant is nonnegative, the roots are real (so any solution to the inequality truly does make the polynomial have real roots). Anyways, have you tried solving that inequality?

Answer (score 8):

Hint: what are the signs of the terms on the left?

Comment: here by substituting $2^a=t$ I am getting an equation in the form : $3t^3+4t^2-8t+4=$ which is not giving any solution. Please suggest.

Comment: @SachinSharmaa:   The first one is a square, so is positive.  Powers of positive numbers are always positive, so the second is, too.  This is general:  given a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $ac \lt 0$, both roots are real.